# What does suptitle really mean in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, suptitle

In using any package, the name of a function should be obvious so that
our brain does not keep remembering weird features.

So in matplotlib, every time I use `suptitle`, I have no idea what "sup" is for.
Does anyone have this problem or do we just use it since the standard said so?

Comment: I always thought it meant super title since it's above all the other titles on the ax objects. That is based on no source or reference.

Comment: Though the duplicate does not reference any "official" source, so it could be a personal interpretation ;)

Comment: Good point. Turns out the devs have officially confirmed it on their issue tracker. @O.rka's "super title" guess is correct.

Comment: Nice catch @tdy ;)

Comment: Haha, wow. One of my greatest achievements.

Comment: Certainly an example 40+ years on in the struggles around software documentation of understanding what the purpose of documentation is: not to reiterate what is obvious about the software ("Add a centered suptitle to the figure." ... Ummm, thanks. Duh?); but to explain intentions, consequences, what can't be assumed or intuited (what is a "suptitle"? what is it intended for? where will it be placed in a graph ("centered", at least); will it launch nuclear bombs, or send all my private photos to Matplotlib?). A little exaggerated, but still documentation should be better than this by now.

Comment: I mean, I thought it would add a little animated hip-hop dude to the center of all my graphs, like images in the center of a QR code, who said " 'sup " to everyone who viewed my figure. I'm disappointed now...

Comment: i asked myself the same question, mainly because I've often confused it with the word "subtitle" (which makes no sense fort this purpose). What a terrible naming (IMHO) to save two characters and confuse people... but that's matplotlib standard i guess :)

Answer (score 2):

"Super title" is the official meaning. This has been [confirmed by the matplotlib devs](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/13388#issuecomment-461790124):

> `suptitle` stands for super title. The word super comes from the latin language, meaning "above." A `suptitle` is hence a title that stands above the axes of the figure, on top of it. This is in contrast to a normal title which is bound to an axes.